# Any attempt to access props in MDX component results in failed build, but dev works just fine

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-props, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I'm trying to get a single line of anything from passed by props to render.

If nothing is passed or needed, then the MDX render outs. If props are passed and tried to be used, failure.

The only thing left on this site is getting MDX to actually render on build.

Running [Gatsby Dev] *works*, and the MDX file renders can use all props passed to it. Any attempt to [Gatsby Build] and it fails saying that it can't read undefined.

I've tried wrapping the render in a MDX provider, in a conditional statement that checks for the specific props first, but nothing works. Gatsby Build pretends like there are no props being passed at all.

**POST TEMPLATE**

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import {graphql, Link} from 'gatsby'
import { MDXProvider } from '@mdx-js/react';
import Layout from "../components2/Layout";
import Navbar from "../components2/Navbar"

**Styled components**

const Post = ({data}) => {
    const { frontmatter} = data.mdx
    onst result = data.mdx;

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <BlogLayout>
        <Container>
                <Banner>
                <BannerInner>
                  <BannerSubtitle to={`/${frontmatter.tags[0]}`}>{frontmatter.tags[0]} 
                  </BannerSubtitle>
                  <BannerTitle>{frontmatter.title}</BannerTitle>
                  <BannerByline><span>{frontmatter.date}</span></BannerByline>
                </BannerInner>
              </Banner>
          </Container>
          <GridWrap>
                <MDXProvider>
                <MDXRenderer props={result}>{result.body}</MDXRenderer>
                </MDXProvider>
          </GridWrap>
        </BlogLayout>
      </Layout>
    );
}


export default Post

export const Pagequery = graphql`query PostBySlug($slug: String!) {
  mdx(slug: {eq: $slug}, frontmatter: {templateKey: {eq: "blog-post"}}) {
    frontmatter {
      title
      date(formatString: "MM/DD/YYYY")
      tags
      featuredimage {
        childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData(placeholder: DOMINANT_COLOR, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
        }
      }
    }
    body
    excerpt
  }
}
`
```

**MARKDOWN FILE**

```
---
templateKey: blog-post
title: Tables with style
date: 3122-03-08T01:54:06.882Z
description: "Nulla neque sem, gravida nec facilisis eu, interdum a neque. Morbi
  in maximus dui. Morbi tincidunt ultrices nulla quis ullamcorper. Etiam egestas
  id nisi in cursus. In in ex luctus, sodales sapien eu, semper ligula. Fusce
  vitae turpis vel dui interdum eleifend nec nec eros. Praesent sed placerat
  lacus. Aliquam lacinia arcu ut sollicitudin dictum. Aenean gravida commodo
  velit, non accumsan tortor congue et. Duis malesuada nibh et odio finibus, a
  fermentum lacus gravida. "
featuredpost: true
featuredimage: /img/44.jpg
tags:
  - table
metaDescription: "Nulla neque sem, gravida nec facilisis eu, interdum a neque.
  Morbi in maximus dui. Morbi tincidunt ultrices nulla quis ullamcorper. Etiam
  egestas id nisi in cursus. In in ex luctus, sodales sapien eu, semper ligula.
  Fusce vitae turpis vel dui interdum eleifend nec nec eros. Praesent sed
  placerat lacus. Aliquam lacinia arcu ut sollicitudin dictum. Aenean gravida
  commodo velit, non accumsan tortor congue et. Duis malesuada nibh et odio
  finibus, a fermentum lacus gravida. "
---

import { getImage, GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";

## Post Body

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eleifend iaculis nunc ut posuere. Integer mollis interdum nisi eu pellentesque. Quisque euismod ipsum mi, in rutrum nisl malesuada quis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam tempor iaculis varius. 

## Local Images

<div className="image-grid">
{this.props.frontmatter.title}
</div>
```

**GATSBY CONFIG**

```
  plugins: [
{
      // keep as first gatsby-source-filesystem plugin for gatsby image support
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/static/img`,
        name: "uploads",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/blog`,
        name: "pages",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
        name: "images",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-local-search',
      options: {
          name: 'pages',
          engine: 'flexsearch',
          query:`
          query {
            allMdx(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }, filter: {frontmatter: {templateKey: {eq: "blog-post"}}}) {
              nodes {
                excerpt
                slug
                body
                frontmatter {
                  date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
                  title
                  tags
                  featuredimage {
                    publicURL
                    childImageSharp {
                      gatsbyImageData(placeholder: DOMINANT_COLOR, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `,
          ref:  'slug',
          index: ['title', 'excerpt'],
          store: ['title', 'excerpt', 'slug', 'tags', 'image'],
          normalizer: ({ data }) =>
          data.allMdx.nodes.map(node => ({
              title: node.frontmatter.title,
              excerpt: node.excerpt,
              slug: node.slug,
              tags: node.frontmatter.tags,
              image: node.frontmatter.featuredimage.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData
          })),
      }
  },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    "gatsby-plugin-image",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
    `gatsby-plugin-remove-fingerprints`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms",
      options: {
        modulePath: `${__dirname}/src/cms/cms.js`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Matt Site`,
        short_name: `Another site`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#6b37bf`,
        theme_color: `#6b37bf`,
        // Enables "Add to Homescreen" prompt and disables browser UI (including back button)
        // see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#display
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `src/images/icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers",
            options:{
            icon: false
          }
        },
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-relative-images",
            options: {
              staticFolderName: 'static',
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              // It's important to specify the maxWidth (in pixels) of
              // the content container as this plugin uses this as the
              // base for generating different widths of each image.
              maxWidth: 2048,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files",
            options: {
              destinationDir: "static",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    
  ],
```

**PACKAGE JSON**

```
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.8",
    "@fontsource/anton": "^4.5.2",
    "@fontsource/epilogue": "^4.5.4",
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^1.6.22",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.6",
    "flexsearch": "^0.7.21",
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.8",
    "gatsby": "^4.1.2",
    "gatsby-awesome-pagination": "^0.3.8",
    "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-emotion": "^7.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-local-search": "^2.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.8.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^3.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "^6.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-remove-fingerprints": "^0.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.10.0-next.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^6.8.1",
    "gatsby-remark-relative-images": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-remark-table-of-contents": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.8.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.10.0-next.2",
    "hamburger-react": "^2.4.1",
    "netlify-cms-app": "^2.15.66",
    "netlify-cms-media-library-cloudinary": "^1.3.10",
    "netlify-cms-media-library-uploadcare": "^0.5.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-collapsed": "^3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-use-flexsearch": "^0.1.1",
    "remark-slug": "^7.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this line:

```js
const Post = ({data}) => {
    if (!data) return null; //add this

    const { frontmatter} = data.mdx
    const result = data.mdx;
```

data is `undefined` until the response of your graphql query comes back, which takes a moment. You can put in a loading screen or some skeleton blocks to render instead of `null` while you wait for it to load.

```
if (!data) return <LoadingScreen />;
```

some other tools that help with this (that you don't need in this case) are:

###### optional chaining

```
const result = data?.mdx
```

###### conditional rendering

```
{ data  &&
  return (
      <Layout>
    ...
}
```

#### Edit

If you are still struggling after trying that, maybe you should, instead of destructing props, console log all the props,

```
const Post = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
```

to inspect whether the shape of the passed props are as you expect.

If that fails too, you can try inspecting the network tab on your browser, and find out whether you are actually receiving the data from gql.

Comment: The solution of ```if (!data) return null;``` Worked great!  



It turned out my previous attempts at using a conditional render weren't working because in the mdx I was trying ```{props.frontmatter.title}``` instead of the the ```{props.props.frontmatter.title``` shape I created.  



Thank you so much! Is there any way I can buy you a coffee or thank you in another way?

Comment: Nah I'm just glad I can help :) congrats on working it out. You can give my answer an upvote though ;)